# Why is in this task used absolute convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Task -> https://ibb.co/1XqhT4z

So this task says: identify if this series converge or diverge:

And this is the solution: https://ibb.co/6tbDCPC

What i do not understand is, why did they use the absolute convergence test in the solution? If they apply absolute convergence, following statement is true |sin(1/n)cosn| <=  sin(1/n) because if we apply absolute convergence test cosn have values in interval [0 ,1].

But the same statement is true if we do not apply the absoulute convergence sin(1/n)cosn <= sin(1/n) because cosn have values on interval [-1 ,1]. Maybe I am wrong but wouldnt it be the same if we did not use the absolute convergence test and just use the comparison criterium?

Comment: Absolute convergence is stronger than conditional convergence.  If, as here, you can show absolute convergence, you should.

Comment: but the task says ,does the following series converge not does it absolutely converge.
Tnx for reply

Comment: In my experience, whenever someone asks if a series converges they want to do both things.  That is, they want to know if it converges absolutely, only conditionally, or diverges.  In any case, it is always good practice to start with absolute convergence.

Comment: Please type your posts, where possible, as in this case, instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed, and may not be legible by all users.  For example, I can't make out the second image except for a symbol here and there.

Comment: I made a link for the picture, is that ok?

Comment: Also worth noting:  it's not easy to use the comparison theorem for conditional convergence alone, it's normally a test for absolute convergence.  To take a silly example, $\sum -\frac 1n$ diverges, though we certainly could compare it to $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$, or even to $\sum 0$.

Comment: Sometimes proving a stronger claim is easier than proving a weaker one. Absolute convergence is easier to prove, and it implies convergence, of course.

Comment: thanks i get it now!
@lulu tnx for the example it helped a lot!